# How to get stacktracejs working with requirejs amd modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs, stacktrace.js

Library:
[Library repo that im using](https://github.com/stacktracejs/stacktrace.js/tree/master/dist)

I just don't think I am getting the point of requirejs that leads me to be incapable of loading in StackTrace from the [stacktrace js library](https://www.stacktracejs.com/#!/docs/stacktrace-js).

I have `stacktrace-with-promises-and-json-polyfills.min.js` saved under `js/lib/stacktrace.js` (I renamed it for a shorter version).

In my config, I tried to add:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "stacktrace": "js/lib/stacktrace"
    }
});
```

Which did not work so I removed them, yet I am able to grab the library from another js module thru:

```
define(['lib/stacktrace'], function(StackTrace) {

    // function is on page load
    function onPageLoad() {
        console.log(StackTrace);
        StackTrace.get().then(/* defined callback */).catch(/*defined */);
    }
}
```

Which is really strange to me that it prints out this with error:

[image: Console logging StackTrace]

I can log the object but all the functions are lost. I have tried with the original `stacktrace.min.js` too. Sometimes `StackTrace` is undefined.

Looking back, I have no idea on how to write a requirejs config to allow stacktrace js library to become a module. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally broke using `dist/stacktrace.js` with module loaders like RequireJS. I'm sorry.

The good news is: I just fixed it. Please give [stacktrace.js v1.3.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stacktrace-js) a try and let me know if it works for you.